# Appium TestNG error : Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end

Tags: appium, web-application, eclipse

I'm trying to launch a simple web application test using Appium, using AVD. I'm using eclipse, and the android studio emulator. I included all the packages. I would like to make sure about the capabilities I used concerning the device name because in the AVD the device name is: 'Nexus6API24' but when I type the command `adb devices` I'm getting:

List of devices attached:

```
emulator-5554 device 
product:sdk_google_phone_x86 
model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 
device:generic_x86
```

Could someone explain the source error?

This is the java code I used:

```
package com.example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class FirstAppiumTest {


// create instance for appium driver
    AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
    @Test

    public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,BrowserType.CHROME);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM,Platform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
        //cap.setCapability("AVD", "emulator-5554");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
        System.out.println("Title "+driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("mukesh@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("mukesh_selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).click();
        driver.quit();

    }


}
```

And I'm getting this error in eclipse ;

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\ghabr\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1101744164\testng-customsuite.xml

[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\ghabr\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1101744164\testng-customsuite.xml

Feb 12, 2017 6:26:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Feb 12, 2017 6:26:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
FAILED: Setup
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-O6MJ7FC6', ip: '192.168.251.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:90)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:128)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:72)
    at com.example.FirstAppiumTest.Setup(FirstAppiumTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
FAILED: Setup
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-O6MJ7FC6', ip: '192.168.251.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:90)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:128)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:72)
    at com.example.FirstAppiumTest.Setup(FirstAppiumTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@82de64a: 38 ms


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@82de64a: 38 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@47e2e487: 740 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 20 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1151e434: 6 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@47e2e487: 740 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 20 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1151e434: 6 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@4efac082: 480 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@4efac082: 480 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@13fd2ccd: 17 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@13fd2ccd: 17 ms
```

And this is the log messages in Appium :

```
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platform":"ANDROID"},"requiredCapabilities":{}},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platform":"ANDROID"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)
> info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : platform
> info: Set mode: Proxying straight through to Chromedriver
> info: [debug] Looks like we want chrome on android
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 960dfc32-859d-4586-9cc6-6bd96e0e2815
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\ghabr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? false
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\ghabr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platform":"ANDROID"},"requiredCapabilities":{}},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platform":"ANDROID"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)
> info: [debug] Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
>     at [object Object].Appium.start (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:139:15)
>     at exports.createSession (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:188:16)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
>     at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:39:7
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
>     at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>     at methodOverride (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\method-override\index.js:79:5)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at trim_prefix (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
>     at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>     at logger (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\morgan\index.js:136:5)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at trim_prefix (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress)","origValue":"Requested a new session but one was in progress"},"sessionId":"960dfc32-859d-4586-9cc6-6bd96e0e2815"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 5841.676 ms - 250 
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
> info: Found device emulator-5554
> info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\ghabr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\ghabr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
> info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\ghabr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.unlock without first uninstalling.]
> 
> info: [debug] Error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.unlock without first uninstalling.]
> 
>     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
>     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>     at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
>     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>     at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\unlock_apk\\unlock_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.unlock without first uninstalling.]\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"origValue":"Command failed: Failed to install C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\unlock_apk\\unlock_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.unlock without first uninstalling.]\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 26332.143 ms - 642
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
```

Try:

```
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
```

That's what I use after reading [Understanding Desired Capabilities](https://nishantverma.gitbooks.io/appium-for-android/understanding_desired_capabilities.html).